# How to check a generic type can be converted to String in swift

Tags: swift, generics

How to check the Generic type can be converted to `String`? Like below,

```
class Stack<T> {
    var values = [T]()

    func debugPrint() {
        values.map {
          String($0) // How to check if $0 can be converted to String?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your class to handle only types that can be casted to a String then change the generics definition so that T conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible`

```
class Stack<T:LosslessStringConvertible>
```

If on the other hand you are only interested in getting a string for printing then you can use `String(describing:)`

```
 values.map {
    String(describing:$0)
 }
```